# How to find emails in many large files

Tags: regex, grep

**OS**
Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit LTS - minimal install- updated.

**Spec:**
2x 6 core Xeon,
12 GB ECC memory,
Storage RAID 10 = 4 TB,
File system = ext4,

Above server is dedicated to this project.

**Desired result:**
Use `grep` more efficiently, get less false positives, and "cleaner" results and export only email accounts to txt file.

**Overview:**
I have many large files in all kinds of formats, .csv, .excel, .txt, .sql etc
Some files are compressed zip, rar, gz etc. (I will be attempting `zgrep` next)
The files reside on a Windows 2012 server, I have mounted the share on the Ubuntu box, and I need to extract all emails to txt file.

I have done tons of researched and played with various regex but cannot get it working 100% as expected.

**Examples:**

**First attempt:**

```
grep -Rs .*@.* . >> emails.txt
```

**Second attempt:** (after research)

```
grep -e '^.*\@.*\..*' -r -n -h >> emails.txt
```

**Third attempt:** (for better performance)

```
LANG=C grep -e '^.*\@.*\..*' -r -n -h >> emails.txt
```

**Fourth attempt:** (even "better" performance, but this depends on hardware)

```
cat * */* */*/* | parallel --pipe -N 250 --round-robin “grep -e '^.*\@.*\..*' -r -n -h >> emails.txt"
```

**The issue:**

With first second and third attempt, I am still getting a ton of "junk" exported.
With the fourth example `cat` still complains about folders, I tried running it with `find .` but then I get only the files that contain the mail accounts in the output.

**Update:** 27/05/2015 - 1:35 GMT +2

After more testing and input from this forum and amazing community i have settled on the below for now:

**grep + email regex Example:**

```
grep -r -o -n -h '[[:alnum:]+\.\_\-]*@[[:alnum:]+\.\_\-]*' . >> emails.txt

grep -r -o -n -h '[[:alnum:]+\.\_\-]*@[[:alnum:]+\.\_\-]*' . >> emails.txt | sort | uniq -i
```

**variations:**

```
grep -ronh '[[:alnum:]+\.\_\-]*@[[:alnum:]+\.\_\-]*' . >> emails.txt

grep -ronh '[[:alnum:]+\.\_\-]*@[[:alnum:]+\.\_\-]*' . >> emails.txt | sort | uniq -i
```

Still testing/ in progress:

**Potential speed increase:**

```
LANG=C grep -ronh '[[:alnum:]+\.\_\-]*@[[:alnum:]+\.\_\-]*' . >> emails.txt

LANG=C grep -ronh '[[:alnum:]+\.\_\-]*@[[:alnum:]+\.\_\-]*' . >> emails.txt | sort | uniq -i
```

**Piping to parallel and splitting into multiple processes (should increase speed hardware dependent):**

```
cat * */* */*/* | parallel --pipe -N 250 --round-robin “grep -ronh '[[:alnum:]+\.\_\-]*@[[:alnum:]+\.\_\-]*' >> emails.txt"

cat * */* */*/* | parallel --pipe -N 250 --round-robin “grep -ronh '[[:alnum:]+\.\_\-]*@[[:alnum:]+\.\_\-]*' >> emails.txt | sort | uniq -i"
```

**Piping to parallel and splitting into multiple processes (should increase speed hardware dependent) including LANG=C:**

```
cat * */* */*/* | parallel --pipe -N 250 --round-robin “LANG=C grep -ronh '[[:alnum:]+\.\_\-]*@[[:alnum:]+\.\_\-]*' >> emails.txt"

cat * */* */*/* | parallel --pipe -N 250 --round-robin “LANG=C grep -ronh '[[:alnum:]+\.\_\-]*@[[:alnum:]+\.\_\-]*' >> emails.txt | sort | uniq -i"
```

Comment: Would doing it in stages work? You could eventually remove junk data in stages.

Comment: You've done a great research, congratulations and welcome in [SO]! To help you better, we like seeing some of your input and expected output, so that we can "play" with it and find better results. Note also that a regular expression to match an email address [is not always very short](http://stackoverflow.com/a/719543/1983854)...

Comment: @npinti - Hi yes, doing it in stages will definitely be the best option.

Comment: @fedorqui thank you helps a ton, and has given me much more insight.

Answer (score 0):

> getting a ton of "junk" exported

You can use a **email regex** that matches better, for example from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8829363/1587329):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0‌​-9]‌​)?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$
```

(but maybe the one by @fedorqui is better suited.)

> I tried running it with `find .` but then I get only the files that
>   contain the mail accounts in the output

The command

```
$ find . -type f -exec cat {} \; | grep myregex
```

gives you the content (it does `cat file` on every item) of every file (the `-type f`) in your current working folder (the `.`). As you see, you can pipe it to `grep` / `xargs` / `parallel` / ...

Comment: Thank you for the input, and pointing me in the right direction. I have formulated the below and it seems to be working well. grep -r -o -n -h '[[:alnum:]+\.\_\-]*@[[:alnum:]+\.\_\-]*' . >> emails.txt

Comment: @Mookz: did you try the `find`-approach instead of using `cat * */* */*/*`?

Comment: yes thanks, "find . -type f -exec cat {} \; | grep -roh '[[:alnum:]+\.\_\-]*@[[:alnum:]+\.\_\-]*'  >> emails.txt" works but cant get "find . -type f -exec cat {} \; | parallel --pipe -N 250 --round-robin “grep -roh '[[:alnum:]+\.\_\-]*@[[:alnum:]+\.\_\-]*’” >> email.txt" to work :(